# Ubuntu 18.04 - What happens if I delete /var/log/syslog?

Tags: 18.04, delete, syslog

This is a two part question. First is there any harm in deleting the syslog or syslog.x files where x is an integer >= 1 in a chain of syslog files. These files are taking up 90% of my disk space.

Details: I'm getting this error in the log file.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog.1`:

```
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
May  5 00:06:22 Skynet org.gnome.Nautilus[2942]: [00007f92580911b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

I found a similar post, [I don't know what is producing the gigabytes of error in syslog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561565/i-dont-know-what-is-producing-the-gigabytes-of-error-in-syslog), and they suggest that VLC is causing this error. I am also using VLC and suspect it's the cause of the problem. How can I free up my disk space?

I was thinking to do something like

```bsh
cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog.1
```

and hope that it will fix it for the time being. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have Nvidia? If so, what model, and what version Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend freeing space by deleting the syslog.*x* and syslog.*x*.gz files first while you work on solving the issue of the logs filling up quickly with these error messages.

My research indicates the issue is likely related to a bug in the package  `nvidia-driver-435`  or VLC or a combination of the two.  See the [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374) here.

You can determine your graphics hardware and driver information by running:

`sudo lshw -c display`

Further details and possible root causes can be found [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561565/i-dont-know-what-is-producing-the-gigabytes-of-error-in-syslog).

As a start, I recommend using a media player other than VLC to see if the log entries cease.

Answer (score 1):

stop the syslog daemon, just delete the file and restart the daemon. This will re-create the file. Command line depends on which syslog daemon you use, in my case i would run:
systemctl stop rsyslogd;   rm /var/log/syslog; systemctl start rsyslog

Comment: I ended up doing that for the syslog.1 file since it was consuming about 80% of the disk space. I don't want to do it on the syslog file as it's currently in use still by other applications so I'm avoiding it for now. It's still taking up about 10% of my disk space, but I can live with that for now. Thanks for your suggestion.